# Number theory (open problem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

consider a set $ A ={1,2,3,3,4,4,.....,n,n,n,...,n}$ . 
such that every k $ \in A$ occurs exactly $ \varphi (k)$ times
where ,$\varphi :\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and it denote number of coprimes before it .
[it is euler's totient funtion]
consider $N_0 =\varphi (1)+......+\varphi (n)$ .
now consider $a_i$ be permutation of the elements of A $ \forall i={1,2,3,.....,N_0}$
prove that for all n we must have a permutation so that 
$ \sum_{i=1}^{N_0} \frac{1}{a_ia_{i+1}}$ =1 consider$N_0 +1 \to 1$

This can't done by me.idk why @guys try it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows. (What have you tried? Where are you stuck? etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you techniques with which you aren't familiar. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) Since comments are easily overlooked, [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3387733/edit) to add details.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the construction is rather simple. Take all *reduced fractions* between 0 and 1 with denominators up to $n$, and sort them in their natural order:
$${1\over5}\dots{1\over4}\dots{1\over3}\dots{2\over5}\dots{1\over2}\dots{3\over5}\dots{2\over3}\dots{3\over4}\dots{4\over5}\dots{1\over1}$$
Now leave just the denominators standing in the same order:
$$5,4,3,5,2,5,3,4,5,1$$
That's the permutation you were after.

The proof is less simple and follows these lines:

1. You can build the [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence) up to any number of terms.
2. To build it, you repeatedly insert [mediants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediant_(mathematics)) between neighboring numbers.
3. Doing so does not change the sum $\sum\dfrac{1}{a_ia_{i+1}}$.

So it goes.

Comment: Please try to elaborate it please don't understand .

Comment: Which part of it you don't understand?

Comment: I got it thanx ,.............